# How to configure webpacker in rails environment to load sass file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

So my question is pretty simple ; I have `webpacker` with rails in my project and I am looking for a way to configure webpacker to load sass files.

I know webpacker creates `/app/javascript/packs` when it is installed but I would like to put my stylesheets files in a directory like `/app/stylesheets` and still get them processed by webpacker

So How should I config `webpacker` to do this job ?

Comment: add `resolved_paths: ['app/stylesheets']` inside your config>webpacker.yml file

Comment: I would recommend following the recommended way of included CSS into Webpacker, instead of trying to force it to use things coming out of the asset pipeline. https://github.com/rails/webpacker#usage. I have Sass working in a Webpacker application, and it required no configuration.

Comment: @sovalina where is webpacker.yml ?

Comment: for the record: here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57956176/1175090