# Adding external js files on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a folder named "custom" under app->javascript->packs and place the following external js:

- `metisMenu.min.js`
- `startmin.js`

Then on under app->javascript->packs->application.js I required the stated js plugin above:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("custom/metisMenu.min").start()
require("custom/startmin").start()
require("channels")


import 'bootstrap'
import './stylesheets/application.scss'
```

Unfortunately, still this did not work. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Also is it ok to place all of the custom css under app->javascript->packs->stylesheets (folder) and not on the assets->stylesheets anymore since Rails 6 is using webpacker?

Comment: Doesn't it work like that? `require("custom/startmin")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your folder needs to be structured like that:

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require("custom")
```

**app/javascript/custom/index.js**

```
require("myScript")
require("mySecondScript")
```

The `myScript.js` and `mySecondScript.js` files, for instance, will be located in the same folder ie `app/javascript/custom`.

Comment: You don't need `.js` extension in the second snippet

Comment: is this also applies to CSS? for instance I have the stylesheet folder and i have the _metisMenu.min.css and _startmin.css files can I also include it under application.scss by adding import "metisMenu.min";
import "startmin"; ???

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom **js** files like this:

1. Add your js files to `app/javascript` folder

   ```
   app/javascript/custom/metisMenu.min.js
   app/javascript/custom/startmin.js
   ```
2. Require js files in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

   ```
   require("@rails/ujs").start()
   require("turbolinks").start()
   require("@rails/activestorage").start()

   # custom js files
   require("custom/metisMenu.min")
   require("custom/startmin")
   ```
3. Add `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` to `application.html.erb`

**UPDATE**

You can add **style** files like this:

1. Add your style files to `app/javascript` folder

   ```
   app/javascript/stylesheets/metisMenu.min.scss
   ```
2. Import style files in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

   ```
   import "stylesheets/metisMenu.min"
   ```
3. Add `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>` to `application.html.erb`
4. Set `extract_css: true` in `config/webpacker.yml`

Comment: is this also applies to CSS? for instance I have the stylesheet folder and i have the _metisMenu.min.css and _startmin.css files can I also include it under application.scss by adding import "metisMenu.min";
import "startmin"; ???

Comment: @JoanBuan Yes you can import sytle files. I updated the answer.

Comment: @demir update your answer with (a) changing `stylesheet_link_tag` with `stylesheet_pack_tag` in `application.html.erb` and (b) setting `extract_css: true` in `config/webpacker.yml`

Comment: @LyzardKyng I assumed stylesheet_pack_tag helper was added. I'il update the answer.